# Why a table has to be outside the PHP block?

Tags: php, html, tags, html-table

Why does a table which started inside the PHP code has to be outside of PHP block to work properly? If I put it inside PHP block it won't work but if its outside it works fine.

```
 <?php
       if(isset($_GET['view_xx'])){
           ?>

               <table class='viewTable'>
           <tr><td  colspan='6'align='center'bgcolor='#669966'>XX Stories</td></tr>
           <tr>
               <th>Page No.</th>
               <th>Title</th>
               <th>Link</th>
               <th>Story</th>
               <th>Options<th>

           </tr>
             <?php
                 $query="SELECT * FROM `z_home`";
                 $run=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
                     $home_title  =substr($row['title'],0,50);
                     $home_id     =$row['a_id'];
                     $home_story  =substr($row['story'],0,50); /* reduce charcter to 100 */
                     $home_imgURL =$row['img_src'];
             ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $home_id ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $home_title ?></td>
                <?php echo"<td><input type='text'value='$home_imgURL' /></td>" ?>
                <td width='20%'><?php echo $home_story ?></td>
                      <td>Delete</td>
                      <td>Edit</td>

              </tr>
            <?php }} ?>
       </table>       why it has to be outside ?


</body>
```

Comment: Otherwise you close it on every iteration of that loop. The `while()` is building multiple rows inside the `{}`. If you want multiple tables open the table inside the `while` as well. `while(){ ?> <table class='viewTable'> <?php ..`.

Comment: urg there's a reason we try not to mix presentation with programming

Comment: I also would move the second `}` after the closing table element, the last one is for the closing the `isset`. If it is not set you won't have an open table.

Comment: You can still keep it inside php block if you use something like `echo "</table>";` . It's the rendered HTML at the end that matters.